# Global Variable in android app

Tags: android, global-variables

What is the best way to store data and have access to it from all activities?
I've read that it's possible in two ways:

- Using a Singleton class
- Using a class that extends Application class

Is there any known issues regarding both solutions? (flip device, app goes to background, receiving a call)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html. use application class

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the Singleton approach.

Usually when there should be data that is accessible to everyone, it is reasonable that someone should manage it, so I would create a Singleton class called [Something]Manager that manages that data and allows access to whatever is relevant to other classes.

I haven't encountered any trouble with the things you mentioned: flip device, app goes to background, receiving a call

Answer (score 0):

I allways use android.app.Application for this.

In your manifest define

```
<application
   android:name="GlobalApplication">
   <activity....
```

Then create a class GlobalApplication like

```
public class GlobalApplication extends Application
{
    /** The current latitude. */
    private double latitude;
    /** The current longitude. */
    private double longitude;

    /**
     * @return the latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude()
    {
       return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * @param latitude the latitude to set
     */
    public void setLatitude(double latitude)
    { 
       this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    /**
      * @return the longitude
      */
    public double getLongitude()
    {
       return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * @param longitude the longitude to set
     */
    public void setLongitude(double longitude)
    {
       this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

And finnaly you can use call these methods from all your activities :

```
longitude = ((GlobalApplication) this.getApplication()).getLongitude();
```